# Pull one column from source table to another table after every insert into the destination table in MySQL 5.6 using a trigger

Tags: mysql

Hi I have two tables Experiment and Result.
I want to create a trigger such that whenever I insert a row into Result table it should pull the latest 'Experiment_Name' that is present in the 'Experiment' table and pull into a column of 'Result' table named 'Experiment_Name'.

```
EXPERIMENT TABLE
Experiment_id(auto_incremented)  Exp_name
1                                  abc

RESULT TABLE
Result_id   Exp_Name       Exp_id
1              abc            1                   
2              abc            1
3              abc            1        


**New Entry Exp name - xyz**

EXPERIMENT TABLE
Experiment_id(auto_incremented)  Exp_name
1                                  abc

2                                  xyz

RESULT TABLE
Result_id   Experiment_id  Experiment_name
1              1                 abc   
2              1                 abc
3              1                 abc  

4              2                 xyz
5              2                 xyz
6              2                 xyz
```

I know how to pull the recent Experiment_id but I am unable to pull the recent 'Exp_Name'

Query for recent Experiment_id which works.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`new`@`%` TRIGGER `worksheet`.`TestResult_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `TestResult` FOR EACH ROW
set new.Experiment_id = (select max(Experiment_id) from TestExperiment)
```

My attempt for pullling recent Experiment_Name

```
CREATE DEFINER=`new`@`%` TRIGGER `worksheet`.`TestResult_BEFORE_INSERT_1` BEFORE INSERT ON `TestResult` FOR EACH ROW
set new.Experiment_Name = (select Experiment_Name from TestExperiment where Experiment_id = max(Experiment_id))
```

Does not work, throws a syntax error.

I am using mysql 5.6. Please someone help me, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TestResult_BEFORE_INSERT_1`
BEFORE INSERT ON `TestResult` FOR EACH ROW
set new.Experiment_Name = (
    select Experiment_Name
    from TestExperiment
    order by Experiment_id desc
    limit 1
);
```

If you want to copy both values (`Experiment_id` and `Experiment_Name`), you can use `SELECT ... INTO ...` syntax, to store the values into local variables, and then copy them into the desired columns:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `TestResult_BEFORE_INSERT`
BEFORE INSERT ON `TestResult` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_id INT;
  DECLARE v_name TEXT;

  SELECT Experiment_id, Experiment_Name INTO v_id, v_name
  FROM TestExperiment
  ORDER BY Experiment_id DESC
  LIMIT 1;

  SET new.Experiment_id   = v_id;
  SET new.Experiment_Name = v_name;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

See demo on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wm6tzrSk7UtvnyoMGT8mgb/0)

Comment: Thanks! but it throws an error : ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Note : There is already an existing trigger for pulling the Experiment_id into the Result table from Experiment table which is mentioned above.

Comment: So you want to copy both values? ID and Name?

Comment: Yes! I want to copy both Experiment_id and Experiment_Name at the same time. Apologies, I thought that could be done in two different queries,I am fairly new to MySQL

Comment: That **can** be done in two queries. But it's also possible to run a single SELECT statement. See my update.